# Automatically mark emails as read in Evolution 3.2.2?

Tags: evolution

How can I change settings in Evolution 3.2.2 so that emails are marked read once I display them? I know this is default behavior of pretty much any email client, however, I just can't find that option anymore. A tick box "Mark emails as read after xxx seconds" used to be found under Preferences/Mail Preferences/General in earlier but it seems gone now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This setting is now in gconf:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/evolution/mail/display/mark_seen_timeout --type int 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, setting the option in gconf works. Do you know if this is some kind of bug or has such a common option been removed from the GUI intentionally? The latter would seem a bizarre design decision to me.

Comment: @wintercorn Yes, this option was removed as it is not widely used, so power users will use gconf to edit this. Here is a [bugreport](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649597)

Comment: I see. I was puzzled as I just wanted to deactivate that option temporarily for some purpose. However, there was the update, and then there was no way to get it back. Probably a special case. I still can't really see why one should suddenly move such a common option from the GUI to gconf but I guess that's Gnome philosophy.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me in Evolution 3.4.4.  Has the key changed?

Comment: For evolution 3.4 onwards this is now in dconf in a different location and in ms: dconf write /org/gnome/evolution/mail/mark-seen-timeout 0

Comment: [This is back in the UI as of evolution 3.6](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evolution-list/2012-August/msg00047.html)

Answer (score 7):

For evolution 3.4 onwards this is now in dconf in a different location and in ms:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/evolution/mail/mark-seen-timeout 0
```

Comment: [This is back in the UI as of evolution 3.6](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evolution-list/2012-August/msg00047.html)

Comment: It's currently on Preferences > Mail Preferences > Mark messages as read after. I'm using version 3.36.3.

Answer (score 2):

For those, like me, who want to turn this to never mark as read, instead of 0, use a pretty big number, so it practically never gets marked read automatically.

or this command turn this feature off

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/evolution/mail/display/mark_seen --type boolean false
```

With more recent evolution version (e.g. 3.12.11), use gsettings instead

```
gsettings set org.gnome.evolution.mail mark-seen false
```

Comment: I set the key as above, confirmed that it was set and restarted Evolution 3.4.3. It still automatically marks messages as read.